# Django: Passing Array Data to Views with Ajax

Tags: arrays, ajax, django, python-3.x, post

I am using ajax to pass an array data to Django (1.10 under Python 3.5) view for further processing. However, I noticed that the passing is not success and results in None. I am wondering what place I have gone wrong and can anyone suggest solution to this. Thanks a lot. Details are as below:

Ajax query to pass array final_ele to view as the variable final_ele_view:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../exportNews/",
    method: "POST",
    data:
    {
        final_ele_view: 'final_ele',
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    }
});
```

Then in the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/exportNews/', views.exportNews),  
    ...
```

Then in views.exportNews:

```
from annoying.decorators import ajax_request
@ajax_request
@csrf_protect    
def exportNews(request):
    arr_tag = request.POST.getlist('final_ele_view[]')            
    return HttpResponse(arr_tag)
```

By the way, I just notice one thing. Even in the ajax I ask for the POST method, but in views.py which shows the method is actually GET (by using return HttpResponse(request.method) ). Is that the reason of the error, and why this happens?

Comment: *What* is resulting in None? Please show the full output or error.

Comment: It just shows a blank webpage with nothing as a result (as I am testing with HttpResponse). When I change the statement to "arr_tag = request.POST.get('final_ele_view')", the webpage writes "None" and nothing more. Does it help?

Comment: And there is no error message I can see in neither the chrome or python console. Or am I missing anything to get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Why the `[]` at the end of `fiinal_ele_view[]`? I bet the `QueryDict` returned from request.POST does not know how to handle square brackets because that's invalid Python syntax.

Comment: I followed some post that when getting list, you have to attach [] after the array name. I may be wrong. And I try to remove the [] from the statement, it still shows nothing on the webpage as the results

Comment: gotcha. Didn't realize that. But is the data actually an array? It looks like you're just sending up a string.

Comment: Yes, it's a array. I have checked that before putting it into ajax. I don't know is the posting would change it to string. Anyway, the problem I am having now is getting nothing after posting, neither list or strings...

Comment: It's not an array. You're sending the literal string "final_ele".